# How can I handle a perl constructor that dies?

Tags: perl, error-handling, die

Code snippet:

```
my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => 'America/San_Francisco');
```

This immediately dies because `America/San_Francisco` is not a [recognized timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List).

The following message is printed:

*The timezone 'America/San_Francisco' could not be loaded, or is an invalid name.*

I would like to handle this error and print additional info for the user before the script exits.  I tried using `unless`, but no luck catching the `die`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `eval { ... }` and `$@` to trap and manage fatal errors.

```
my $tz = eval { DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => 'America/San_Francisco') };
if (!$tz) {
    if ($@ =~ /The timezone .* could not be loaded/) {
        warn "Choose a timezone from ", 
            "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List";
    } else {
        warn "Error in DateTime::TimeZone constructor: $@";
    }
    exit 1;
}
```

Comment: This almost works, but gives me a strange error:
`Choose a timezone from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List at ./test-die.pl line 6, <DATA> line 1.`

Comment: `my $tz; eval { $tz = .... ; 1 } or do { if ($@ =~` is safer. `$@` might be clobbered in some Perl versions. See [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny) and [Bug in eval in pre-5.14](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1153468).

Comment: @JonathanCross Add a `\n` to the end of the string to prevent the location from being included.

Comment: Try::Tiny is safer than evals.

Comment: @choroba, `my $tz = eval { ... } or do { ... };` would suffice since `DateTime::TimeZone->new` always returns a true value.